# Fail to build StarRocks FE

Tags: java, maven, starrocks

When I was trying to build StarRocks on my Mac, I met an error. Following is error messaging

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:19 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-06-14T08:39:27+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project fe-core: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.starrocks:fe-core:jar:3.4.0: com.starrocks:spark-dpp:jar:1.0.0 was not found in https://mirror.iscas.ac.cn/kunpeng/maven/ during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of kunpeng has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

My Java version is

```
openjdk version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-86)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-86, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Did you use the build.sh script to build the project?
You can build the hole fe project using the command `sh build.sh --fe`.
If you only want to build the spark-dpp module, you can using the command `mvn package -pl "fe-common,spark-dpp" -DskipTests` in the fe dir, and you can find the result in fe/spark-dpp/target/

Comment: Thanks, it helped me.
Because I'm going to build StarRocks on my Mac, `build.sh` doesn't work for me.
When I run `mvn install -DskipTests` in `fe` directory, it worked.
However, I need to install `thrift@0.13.0` first.